# CSS adjust height of iframe as screen gets wider

Tags: html, css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 grid columns to adjust the width of an iframe, however, if I set the height of the iframe, it is to tall on mobile devices, and if I dont set the height of the iframe, it is too short on desktops, here is my code

```
<iframe class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?= $hash ?>" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can I automatically increase the height of the iframe for different resolutions?

## EDIT

With `height: auto`, the youtube embed looks like this

[image: youtube embed screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try making width as 100% and auto height. Perhaps, try moving that into separate class, as inline css is used as an example below:

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: auto;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?= $hash ?>" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, it didn't work, please see the screenshot I have just attached to this question